# Congratulations to our ♦moderators JohnP, Alec, and C. Lange on their appointment today!

Tags: discussion, moderators

[Our first election](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/election/1) ended early since we had only 3 candidates, congratulations to all three ♦moderators (two of them who served us well during the Beta phase, and C. Lange who joined the ♦team today)!

Thanks to all of you for putting your names forward and volunteering to help keep this site healthy!  I look forward to many more great years together :)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you -- I am looking forward to working with JohnP and Alec.

If anyone ever wants to discuss anything feel free to `@ping` me in the Locker Room chat. I am always free to discuss powerlifting and getting stronger!